# Pop matching elements from array, then push them back

Tags: ruby, arrays

Say I have an array: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Given another array (`[2, 4]`, for example), I would like to have a new array (or the initial array modified, doesn't matter) that looks like: `[1, 3, 5, 2, 4]`. So selected elements are moved to the end of the array.

Pushing the elements back is quite straight-forward, but how do I pop specific elements from an array?

Comment: Given another array `[4,2]`, should the result be `[1, 3, 5, 2, 4]` or `[1, 3, 5, 4, 2]`, or either?

Comment: The elements should best be pushed in the same order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [2, 4]

(a - b) + (b & a)
#=> [1, 3, 5, 2, 4]
```

`a - b` is the elements in `a` but not in `b`, while `b & a` is the elements that are common in both arrays. There goes your expected result.

Comment: I would `(a-b)+(b&a)` to save the order of elements in the second array. Though it depends on what OP desired.

Comment: If the elements of `a` are not unique, the result might not be what is expected.

Comment: Why not just `(a-b) + b`

Comment: I suggest you make `b = [4,2]`, and then `(a-b) + b #=> [1, 3, 5, 4, 2]` or 
`(a-b) + (a&b) #=> [1, 3, 5, 2, 4] `, depending on the desired order of the last two elements.

Answer (score 1):

In case if elements in `a` are not uniq (as mentioned by eugen) and it's important to remove only one element from `b` you could do something like:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 2]
b = [2, 4, 7]
p (b&a).unshift(a.map{|el|
    b.include?(el) ? begin b = b -[el]; nil end : el
  }.compact).flatten

#=> [1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 2, 2, 4]
```